# GitHub: Find old trending repository lists

Tags: c#, github, repository, static-analysis, corpus

I want to run some static analysis over a large group of C# repositories. I usually look at the top 25 trending list on GitHub but now they are mostly Pokemon Go bots (not a very representative sample). Is there any way to either:

- Look at last month's trending list.
- Look at a trending list for a longer time frame